# jQuery database display and manipulation plugin?

Tags: jquery, database, sorting, drag-and-drop

I'm looking for a jQuery-based way of displaying data from a database (array, etc) and then has the capability of re-arranging the database data via drag and dropping. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Searching through here could help: http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/datagrid

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for DataGrid component then i strongly advice [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) and you can find a demo [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/).
But if you look for solution based on *form structure* [jQuery Collections plugin](http://jsguy.com/?p=55) will help you.